# How Can I Make All Checkboxes "Checked" By Default

Tags: checkbox, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I ensure by default all by checkboxes (output from my data) are all checked by default on load?

**Output checkbox**

```
<div v-for="(category, index) in remove_category_duplicates" class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" v-model="cat_data" :id="category" :value="category">
    <label class="form-check-label">{{ category }}</label>
</div>
```

**Setup checkbox values from data**

```
    remove_category_duplicates: function () {
        // Get all categories and remove duplicates
        let data = {}
        this.info.forEach(i=>{
            Object.assign(data,i.category_data);
        })

        return data;
    },
```

**Data:**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Title one",
    "category_data": {
        "2": "Team",
        "7": "Queries"
    }
},
```

**CodePen**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XxNORW?editors=1011

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize the checkboxes to true/checked, their `v-model` array (`cat_data`) should contain the `true`-value of each checkbox. In this case, it would be:

```
["Team", "Questions", "Queries", "Fax"]
```

Here's how I would update your code:

1. Add a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) to return an array of available categories:

   ```
   computed: {
     categories() {
       const cats = this.remove_category_duplicates;
       return Object.keys(cats).map(k => cats[k]);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Update `select()` to set `cat_data` based on `selectAll`. If `selectAll` is true, set `cat_data` to the category array computed above (thus marking all boxes checked), or else an empty array (thus unchecking all boxes):

   ```
   methods: {
     select() {
       this.cat_data = this.selectAll ? this.categories : [];
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add a method (e.g., named "toggleSelectAll") to toggle `selectAll` based on whether all checkboxes are checked, keeping the *Select All* checkbox in sync with the state of the other checkboxes:

   ```
   methods: {
     toggleSelectAll(e) {
       const checked = e.currentTarget.checked;
       if (checked) {
         this.selectAll = this.arrayContains(this.categories, this.cat_data);
       } else {
         this.selectAll = false;
       }
     }
   }
   ```
4. Add a `change`-handler on each checkbox (except the *Select All* box) that calls `toggleSelectAll` defined above:

   ```
   <div v-for="category in remove_category_duplicates">
     <input type="checkbox" @change="toggleSelectAll">
   ```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/yRbVYp?editors=1011)

Comment: That's great, thanks for the insight it works almost perfectly. The only issue I see is if I de-select each checkbox leaving only "All" selected, nothing is returned within the array. Whereas "All" should return, all results. Thanks again.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks so much. Interestingly, when I add this locally querying an API URL it does not work. Is that because of a delay loading the data? My API url is setup within the mounted call. Cheers

Comment: Sounds like a different problem. It's best to ask that as a new question so that others could provide an answer you might find helpful. Make sure to clarify what "doesn't work" means and provide a demo if possible.

Comment: Thanks, yes your right there. Appreciated your help here.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to word the question, but I detail the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757640/axios-get-api-call-causing-unexpected-behaviour