# Axios Get API Call Causing Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

My CodePen below is a working example of what should be happening. Everything there is working as expected. I am using hard coded data there.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XxNORW?editors=0001

**Hard coded data:**

```
info:[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Title one",
    "category_data": {
        "2": "Team",
        "7": "Queries"
    }
}
],
```

**Issue:**

When I replace the hard coded data with an AXIOS get call, the CodePen checkboxes do not function as expected. The **All** checkbox is correctly checked, however **the rest are not**.

I'm assuming, the slight delay in loading the API is the cause of this.

```
mounted() {
   this.getData(); 
},
methods: {
    getData: function() {
      axios
       .get('https://EXAMPLE.com/API/')
      .then(response => {
        this.info = response.data
        this.dataReady = true
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
       this.errored = true
  })
       .finally(() => this.loading = false)
    }
},
```

I do not load the front-end until the data is ready.

How can I remedy this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your demo, calling `select()` asserts the "Select All" feature (checking all checkboxes), but those checkboxes aren't available until `getData()` resolves, so just move `select()` after `getData()`:

```
async mounted() {
  await this.getData();
  this.select();
},
methods: {
  async getData() {
    const {data} = await axios.get(/* URL TO API DATA */);
    this.info = data;
  },
  // ...
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/pxwzxV?editors=1011)

Comment: How do you get to this level of knowledge...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While using **axios** inside your **vue js** application, you are using 'this' keyword inside **axios** which makes it confusing for compiler to which object your are trying to refer **axios** or vue, so to solve this problem try below code:

```
getData: function() {
   let app = this;
  axios
   .get('https://EXAMPLE.com/API/')
  .then(response => {
    app.info = response.data
    app.dataReady = true
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
   app.errored = true
  })
   .finally(() => app.loading = false)
  }
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, would I still return the data from the main info variable like this.info or app.info outside of this function?

Comment: yeah you will still return the variable this.info or app.info outside of this function :)